# State is not updating using setState in geolocation function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, geolocation

I'm trying to update state when I get coordinates from geolocation api. But the state is not updating. I have put callback inside setState to check what it is getting to update coordinates, and it is undefined. 
But I can't figure out where should I put this setState to update actual coordinates.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // App State
    this.state = {
      lat: 0,
      lng: 0
    };
  }
  // ComponentDIDMount
  componentDidMount() {
    // Get Data from json file

    $.getJSON("../resturants.json", data => {
      this.setState({
        resturantsList: data
      });
    });

    // Get location of user
    let success = position => {
      const latitude = position.coords.latitude;
      const longitude = position.coords.longitude;
      console.log(latitude, longitude);
      this.setState(
        {
          lat: latitude,
          lng: longitude
        },
        () => console.log(latitude, longitude)
      );
      console.log(this.state);
    };

    function error() {
      console.log("Unable to retrieve your location");
    }
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);

    // Api call for resturants data
    const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
    const url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=${this.state.lat},${this.state.lng}&radius=3000&type=restaurant&key=apikey`;
    console.log(url);
    fetch(proxyurl + url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        result => {
          console.log(result.results);
          let apiResturants = result.results;
          let allResturants = this.state.resturantsList.concat(
            ...apiResturants
          );
          this.setState({
            resturantsList: allResturants
          });
        },

        error => {
          console.log("error");
        }
      );
  }
  }

  // Render function for app component
  render() {


  }
}
```

Comment: You shall not to init state using `this.state=...`

Comment: And the state update is async, kindly check the official document

Comment: Can you please tell me how this async update affecting state update.

Comment: Check this https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Comment: well if your log is giving undefined then obviously the problem here is not React or setState but rather, your API is not returning what you think it's returning. Log `position` and see if it gives anything. If not you need to take a look at your `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` to see if you're using it correctly.

Comment: As you can see I'm logging coordinates just before setState, and it is giving accurate value.

Comment: oh I see. the log we see in the code isn't the one returning undefined.

Comment: Yes, it was callback function in setState but now I'm seeing that it also give accurate values. But the state is still not updating.

Comment: Can you include a properly formatted and complete code snippet? You don't make asynchronous calls within the constructor in react and you don't call `setState` there either, that is what component lifecycle functions like `componentDidMount` are for. [Source](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor)

Comment: Have a look at the code now.

Comment: Ah yes, react state updates are asynchronous. They are all queued up during a single render cycle *then* processed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HERE IS THE SOLUTION:

```js
const getData = () => {
// Api call for resturants data
    const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
    const url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=${this.state.lat},${this.state.lng}&radius=3000&type=restaurant&key=apikey`;
    console.log(url);
    fetch(proxyurl + url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        result => {
          console.log(result.results);
          let apiResturants = result.results;
          let allResturants = this.state.resturantsList.concat(
            ...apiResturants
          );
          this.setState({
            resturantsList: allResturants
          });
        },

        error => {
          console.log("error");
        }
      );
  }
}


componentDidMount(){

  const success = position => {
  this.setState({lat: position.latitude, long: position.longitude}, () => {
  this.getData();
  })
  }
}
```

setState is async operation, which means the state update will be completed in future time. If you want to check when the state updates, you can use the second argument.

```
this.setState({lat:latitude, long: longitude}, () => {console.log(this.state)});
```

This second callback will tell you the exact issue, as it will be called once the state updation is completed.

Comment: Ok, now I see that the callback is also returning accurate location, but how do I make setState to make state update when he gets accurate value. i.e lat/lng

Comment: if you are console logging the state inside your callback and getting correct results, which means the state has been updated.

Comment: You are absolutely right, but I have an api call which takes location variable from the state. And it does not make request even after state is updated that is what makes me think that state is not updating.

Comment: const url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=${this.state.lat},${this.state.lng}&radius=3000&type=restaurant&key=apikey`

Comment: You are using state data for url, but that will not trigger the request automatically. The state update will only trigger the rerender. Either you have to make the request call in componentDidMount or somewhere else.Or you can explain bit more, if I'm missing something.

Comment: Okay. first console.log(this.state) put this inside the second argument (callback) of setState. it will give you state data once the setState is done running. Second, you are making the API call which supposed to use the state data in componentDidMount which only executes when the component mounts not updates.

Comment: Solution is seperate out the API call in a method and call that method inside the second argument of setState callback. Updating the answer for it.

Comment: But isn't url variables (this.state.lat/this.state.lng) udpate on state update? That is what I learned.

Comment: The the api call gets triggered just after the setState till that time the state is undefined due to it's async nature. Updated the answer please check.

Comment: consider Accepting the answer and up voting,  If I was able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Don't make asynchronous calls and don't call `this.setState` within react components' [constructor](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor).

> You **should not call setState()** in the constructor().

Use the `componentDidMount` lifecycle function to fetch data and update state.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  // App State
  this.state = {
    lat: 0,
    lng: 0
  }
};

componentDidMount() {
  // Get location of user
  const success = position => {
    const latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    const longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    console.log(latitude, longitude);
    this.setState({
      lat: latitude,
      lng: longitude
    });
  };

  const error = () => {
    console.log("Unable to retrieve your location");
  };

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
}
```

**State Update are Asynchronous**

React state updates are asynchronous and queued up for processing at the end of the current render cycle. You're accessing state values from the **current** render cycle, not the one's for the next cycle. Move the lat and long values saved from the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` call into the function scope of `componentDidMount` and use them in the later `fetch` versus using the state `lat` & `lng`.

```
componentDidMount() {
  // Get Data from json file

  $.getJSON("../resturants.json", data => {
    this.setState({
      resturantsList: data
    });
  });

  // Get location of user
  // Move latitude and longitude to function scope
  let latitude = 0;
  let longitude = 0;

  let success = position => {
    // cache values
    latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    console.log(latitude, longitude);
    this.setState(
      {
        lat: latitude,
        lng: longitude
      },
      () => console.log(latitude, longitude)
    );
    console.log(this.state);
  };

  function error() {
    console.log("Unable to retrieve your location");
  }
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);

  // Api call for resturants data
  const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
  // use cached lat & long values
  const url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=${
    latitude
  },${longitude}&radius=3000&type=restaurant&key=apikey`;
  console.log(url);
  fetch(proxyurl + url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
      result => {
        console.log(result.results);
        let apiResturants = result.results;
        let allResturants = this.state.resturantsList.concat(
          ...apiResturants
        );
        this.setState({
          resturantsList: allResturants
        });
      },

      error => {
        console.log("error");
      }
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, ComponentDidMount was there. I just didn't included it at first. My bad.

Comment: @Mehmood Updated answer to explain why the state update can't be accessed later within the same function, and offer a possible solution.

Comment: Hi, and thanks. I have my answer. Check out @oneJeet answer.

Comment: @user1864070 Thanks. Yeah, I don't consider chaining `setState` callbacks to make *further* state updates to be a good pattern, this is what the component lifecycle functions are for.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in a fat arrow function, you can redefine your this by using `let self = this`, then use self.setState instead

Comment: Where would be this line? let self = this. Inside success function?